# How do i make my html and css functioning by adding the script of "python"?

Tags: python, html, css

I created a Log-In form using HTML&CSS quite some days ago! Now after having it seem and perhaps look impressive I lack in functionality even though I have written the python code in PYCharm I am not aware of how to add the python code into my HTML AND CSS and make it functioning.

```
'''
selection = input(
    'Enter The Shape : '
)
if selection == "rectangle":
    Length = float(input("Enter the length(in cm): "))
    breadth = float(input("Enter the breadth(in cm) "))
    Area = Length * breadth
    print("Details About The Rectangle:")
    print('Length :', Length, "cm")
    print('Breadth :', breadth)
    print(
        'Area : ', Area
    )
# if selection != "rectangle":
#     print(
#         'Either You left a space at the end or the shape you entered do not exist'
#     )
if selection == "cube":
    Side = float(input(
        'Enter Length of the side :'
    ))
    area_of = Side * Side * Side
    print(
        "cube's Details : ", Side, "cm length of the side"
    )
    print(
        'Area of the Cube:', area_of, "cm"
    )
# else:

if selection == "cylinder":
    radius = float(input(
        'Enter Radius value : '
    ))
    height = float(input(
        'Enter Height\'s value:'
     ))
    tsa= "tsa" and "TSA"
    TSA = 2 * 3.14 * radius * (height + radius)
    CSA = 2 * 3.14 * radius * height
    which = input(
        'What measurement do you want to find out (TSA,CSA OR VOLUME) :'
    )
    if which == tsa:
        print(
            'Tsa of cylinder is :', TSA
        )
    # else:
    #     print('Either you left a space at the end or such measurement do not exist')
    if which == "CSA" or "csa":
        print(
            'Csa of cylinder is :', CSA
        )
    else:
        print('Either you left a space at the end or such measurement do not exist')
        Volume = 3.14 * radius * radius * height
        if which == "volume":
            print(
                'Volume of cylinder is :', Volume
            )
        else:
            print('Either you left a space at the end or such measurement do not exist')


# else:
#     print(
#         'Either You left a space at the end or the shape you entered do not exist'
#     )
'''
```

Comment: Just ignore my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use frameworks like `Flask` or `Django`

Flask can help you fast

Comment: can you explain me what is FLASK and all I am a newbie

Comment: my actual question is that how can I attach python to HTML and make my page functional ?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not exactly well explained but as far as I understand, you are trying to use the HTML forms to GET the required information to do calculations.

There are many ways to achieve this but the 2 simplest things you can do to link python with HTML are [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) and [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/index.html).

Here is a sample code showing how Flask can be used

```
enter code 
# Simple Flask app to calculate area of a circle


# Imports
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

# Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)


# Function to calculate area of a circle
def areaOfCircle(radius):
    area = 3.14 * radius * radius
    return area




# Route to calculate area of a circle
@app.route('/areaOfCircle', methods=['POST'])  #localhost:5000/areaOfCircle
 def calculateArea():
    # Get the radius from the request 
    radius = request.form['radius']
    # Calculate the area
    area = areaOfCircle(radius)
    # Return the result
    return render_template('areaOfCircle.html', area=area)
```

I suggest you go through the documentation to understand more

Comment: Thanks mate... i agree my qs wasnt explained well and I inserted the wrong script

Comment: @LunaticXXD10 - There are *many* Flask tutorials online.  A little internet searching and you’ll be on your way.